# Formula to grab specific cells and concatenate them together but only if they are not blank

Tags: google-sheets, worksheet-function, concatenate

I have a formula that breaks when 'nothing' is in any of the cells:

```
=If(ISBLANK(A1),,A1&IF(ISBLANK(B1),,CHAR(10)&B1&IF(ISBLANK(C1),,CHAR(10)&C1)))
```

I'm expecting this of course, as I haven't told it to do anything when `ISBLANK` is `TRUE`.

Am I going in the right direction with this or is there a simpler way?

Because I am afraid that I will have to do every scenario for every TRUE FALSE in each `IF()` branch and my real problem is that it has 19 cells that I would like to use if they contain something.

I have a sample sheet here "[Concat Cells if not empty](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1c3r8HY65pljtfVAcEGEAJ99b7Rl86pQ1PdolmwXyUbE/edit?usp=sharing)".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you find yourself writing a bunch of similar IF statement, you probably need [`FILTER`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197).  For example,

```
=JOIN(CHAR(10), FILTER(A1:F1, NOT(ISBLANK(A1:F1))))
```

joins the content of cells A1 through F1, separating them with linebreaks — but the empty cells are skipped as they fail the condition  `NOT(ISBLANK(...))`.

Comment: OK I can see how it works with a range how about individual cells.  for example: I only need the following cells A1, F1, L1, V1  and to separate them with linebreaks.

Comment: If you have to put together several cells scattered around a spreadsheet, I suggest adding another row/column with `=A1 =F1 =L1 =V1` in it, and then joining that row as above.